# css file is not applied to html generated

Tags: android, html, css

In android app, I need to dynamically generate html and load that into webview with loadData. And one of the code includes

```
total.append("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file:///android_asset/main.css\" />");
```

The css file is located in assets folder and has its content

```
body {
color: #3f2000;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,
            right top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#101000));
}
```

And the generated html is

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///android_asset/main.css" />                                
</head>
<body>...
```

But the generated html on WebView does not have background or foreground colors specified in the css. Anybody know why?

**UPDATE: I believe this is clearly a bug in loadData of WebView. I just tried loadDataWithBaseUrl with same string, it worked!**

Comment: Where are you testing? If you search in Google, you will find that this does not work on all devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible that the browser requests and find the css file located in your assets directory.
I dont know about the complexity of your page but what about writing the css content directly in the html file?

e.g

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
 body{...}
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect it impossible. That seems like an obvious solution. Thanks.